# how to match exact list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, match

pleasee help
[google](https://www.google.com.my/search?es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=667&q=comparing%20element%20in%20two%20list%20prolog&oq=comparing%20element%20in%20two%20list%20prolog&gs_l=serp.3...56932.65236.0.65360.38.23.0.0.0.0.803.1167.3-1j6-1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..37.1.803.qfTs1pqguC4)

```
**fact:**
protein(annexin,[a,s,d,f]).

**rules:**
(i dont know)
```

---

```
**query:**
protein(N,[q,w,e,a,s,d,f])
**result:**
N= annexin

**query:**
protein(N,[q,w,e,a,s,d,f,w,o,e])
**result:**
N= annexin
```

Comment: Could you be a few more explicit about the question? It seems you want to search in facts "protein" the ones who contains (sublist) a given sequence. Is it?

Answer (score 2):

`a` is adenin, but what are those non-canonical bases? In any way, let's use a [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg).

```
protein(annexin) -->
   [a,s,d,f].

withprotein(Protein) -->
   ...,
   protein(Protein),
   ... .

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Usage:

```
?- phrase(withprotein(Protein), [q,w,e,a,s,d,f,w,o,e]).
   Protein = annexin
;  false.
```

Comment: It is the name for the non-terminal `... //0` which means: "Just any possibly empty sequence"

Comment: @NorwahidaShamsuddin: Why did you attempt to delete the definition of `... //0`?

Answer (score 0):

A string contains a protein if and only if its definition is a sublist of the string:

```
protein(annexin, [a,s,d,f]).

has_protein(Protein, List) :-
  protein(Protein, ProteinDefinition),
  sublist(ProteinDefinition, List).
```